# Virtual Box Connectivity - Via RDP (With VPN) on VM

Tags: virtualbox, ipv6, macos-sierra, remote-desktop, ipv4

First off, the base question: how to reliably achieve IP/DNS resolution on a mixed network (Linux, Windows, Mac OS), on a common private physical network using IPV4/6, to hosted VM'S that may or may not have VPN's active and DHCP - without an internal DNS.

My Setup:
I run a Windows 10 Host machine with a static IPV4 address, which powers multiple Windows 10, and Linux VM's. Some of the VM's access VPN's, which run IPV4/6 VPN networks. Presently I use a Mac OS computer to RDP to the host system, and I use the Virtual Box GUI to access the systems from there.

I have tried using RDP (Microsoft), to access the VMs independently from my Mac OS system, however this only works through the Local IPV4 address when the VPN is not active - or the IPV6 address with the limitations noted below.

I have also tried using the IPV6 address; and while this works some of the time, I have have mixed to unpredictable results with this on reboots/IP refreshes. The IPV6 Address changes periodically, and I have to log into the router to determine the new address and update RDP entries accordingly.

What I am trying to achieve:

Mac OS system Source system, and RDP to multiple Physical/Virtual machines on the network, while maintaining connectivity through VPN connections on the VMs - Without having to manually type in/keep up with IPV6 addresses.

My hardware is all consumer grade, with a Netgear router (R6400).

While currently I use a single NIC in the VM host, I do have multiple NIC's if that will correct the connectivity issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS-Windows implements RFC-4941 and RFC-7721, for security considerations, that lead to IPv6 address changes (this should not be a problem if you had DNS updates, but this is not your situation).

To avoid IPv6 changes, just use the following 4 lines on your Windows hosts:

```
netsh interface ipv6 set privacy state=disabled store=active
netsh interface ipv6 set privacy state=disabled store=persistent
netsh interface ipv6 set global randomizeidentifiers=disabled store=active
netsh interface ipv6 set global randomizeidentifiers=disabled store=persistent
```

You should now get predictable results.

Comment: Worked like a charm; thanks for taking the time to answer an admittedly obscure question!